# sort order for a custom post-type

Tags: custom-post-types, sort

How do I specify a sort order for a custom post-type like I can do with the pages post-type?

All I have been able to find online is various plugins that do it for me, but I'd prefer not to use a plugin and just insert the code myself.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: sort order by what? would be great if you clarify a little more your question :)

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to sort by menu_order, so I just added support for that when I registered the post-type.

Comment: Hey Jason, how about posting that has an answer that can be accepted to mark this as solved?